# ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:period_registration=>{}, :controller=>"period_registrations", :action=>"save_period"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a nested route:

```
resources :period_registrations do
  member do
    post :save_period
  end
```

that points to my controller action:

```
 def save_period
    @period_registration = PeriodRegistration.new(params[:registration])
    @period_registration.save
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

and I have a test:

```
test "should get save_period" do
    sign_in(FactoryGirl.create(:user))
     assert_difference('Event.count') do
      post :save_period, period_registration: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:period_registration)
    end
    assert_not_nil assigns(:period_registration)

    assert_response :success
  end
```

That when run generates the following error:

```
 1) Error:
test_should_get_save_period(PeriodRegistrationsControllerTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:period_registration=>{}, :controller=>"period_registrations", :action=>"save_period"}
```

What looks odd to me is that :period_registration is empty. Should it be? How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`post` should be defined for `collection`, i.e. you need to change your routing:

```
post :save_period, :on => :collection
```

instead of `member` block. As an example, rails build-in `create` (generated by the `resources`) method also binded to a collection.

Additional notes:

1. You have an error in your controller: `PeriodRegistration.new(params[:registration])`, but should be `PeriodRegistration.new(params[:period_registration])`.
2. And there is a typo in test: `should get save_period` => `should post save_period`

Comment: so all I need to do is add `post :save_period, :on => :collection` correct?